# "Int" object is not iterable

Tags: python, object, int, iterable

I'm trying to run a for loop. Here's the section of my code I'm having trouble with:

```
aldurstengd_ororka = {(18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24):1, (25):0.95, (26):0.90,
    (27):0.85, (28, 29):0.75, (30, 31):0.65, (32, 33):0.55, (34, 35):0.45,
    (36, 37):0.35, (40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45):0.15, (46, 47, 48, 49, 50):0.10,
    (51, 52, 53, 54, 55):0.075, (56, 57, 58, 59, 60):0.05, (61, 62, 63, 64,
    65, 66):0.025}

for age in aldurstengd_ororka.keys():
    for item in age:
       if ororkualdur == item:
           baetur = baetur + ororkulifeyrir * aldurstengd_ororka([age])
```

So my intention is to run through aldurstengd_ororka, and for each "age" tuple in the dictionary, I run another for loop for each "item" inside the tuple. The error I get is

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: It would help if you'll add a tag with the programming language you're using

Comment: @alfasin looks like Python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `aldurstengd_ororka` is a dictionary, then this expression:

```
aldurstengd_ororka([age])
```

is an error. Perhaps you meant something like:

```
aldurstengd_ororka[(age)]
```

EDIT: The error you were seeing is quite interesting, I did reproduce it with this snippet:

```
for age in aldurstengd_ororka.keys():
    print 'age:', age 
    for item in age:
        print item
```

The output of the code is:

```
age: (32, 33)
32
33
age: (36, 37)
36
37
age: (51, 52, 53, 54, 55)
51
52
53
54
55
age: (61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66)
61
62
63
64
65
66
age: (30, 31)
30
31
age: 25
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/ma/mak/Documents/t.py in <module>()
      3 for age in aldurstengd_ororka.keys():
      4     print 'age:', age
----> 5     for item in age:
      6         print item
      7 

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

So, what happens is Python 'unpacks' a tuple of 1 element when assigning it to the age variable. So age instead of `(25)`, as you would expect, is just `25`... It's a bit strange. A workaround would be to do something like:

```
for age in aldurstengd_ororka.keys():
    # if not tuple, make it a tuple:
    if not type(age) == type( (0,1) ): age = (age,)
    print 'age:', age 
    for item in age:
        print item
```

Comment: worked for me as well..(!) found this just before submitting my own (somewhat different) question.

Answer (score 2):

Your tuple keys that just have a single int in them are being parsed as an int instead of a tuple. So when you try to for item in age - you're trying to iterate through a non-iterable. Use lists `[4]` or use a comma `(4,)`, and it'll do the trick:

```
aldurstengd_ororka = {(18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24):1, (25):0.95, (26):0.90,
    (27):0.85, (28, 29):0.75, (30, 31):0.65, (32, 33):0.55, (34, 35):0.45,
    (36, 37):0.35, (40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45):0.15, (46, 47, 48, 49, 50):0.10,
    (51, 52, 53, 54, 55):0.075, (56, 57, 58, 59, 60):0.05, (61, 62, 63, 64,
    65, 66):0.025}

for age in aldurstengd_ororka.keys():
    if isinstance(age, [tuple, list]):
       for item in age:
           if ororkualdur == item:
               baetur = baetur + ororkulifeyrir * aldurstengd_ororka[age]
    else:
        baetur = baetur + ororkulifeyrir * aldurstengd_ororka[age]
```

Answer (score 2):

I hate to say this, but both sihrc and piokuc are wrong.

You have a dictionary of the format:

```
d = { (1,2,3) : "a",
      (4) : "b"
    }
```

The first key `(1,2,3)` is a tuple with 3 integers in it. The second key `(4)` is just an integer with the value 4, *not* a tuple. The defining characteristic of a tuple is the comma separating the values, not the braces, thus `a = 1,2,3` creates a tuple, and assigns it to `a`.

The main purpose of braces around tuples is to make the code look cleaner and to simplify some of the edge cases, such as single item tuples.

To convert the 4 into a single item tuple, you need to do something slightly odd, add a trailing comma after the value, thus `(4,)`.

If you do this to all the single item keys in your dictionary, you should find that it work OK.

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary keys are sometimes tuples and sometimes integers.  As @Simon Callan mentioned you can add commas to the numbers to make all keys iterable.

If you do not wish to edit your dictionary, use a tool from the [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) library that always returns an iterable.

Reduced Example:

```
import more_itertools as mit

d = {
    (18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24): 1, 
    (25): 0.95, 
    (26): 0.90,
    (27): 0.85, 
    (28, 29): 0.75,
}

for age in d:
    for item in mit.always_iterable(age):
        # Add logic here
        pass

# No TypeError
```

See [the docs](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.always_iterable) for details.