# Retrieve Method giving TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, object, int, typeerror, iterable

When I removed the convenience api, an issue that arises is `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` and points to this line `id, = args[0]` ... how would I go about fixing this? Is the issue that I am assigning args[0] similar to this [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17999752/int-object-is-not-iterable) question?

CODE:
 
**object.py** *(parent class)*

```
def retrieve_assessment_result(self, *args):
    id, owner, assessment = None, None, None
    if len(args) == 1:
        id, = args[0]
    elif len(args) == 2:
        owner, assessment = args
        print 'testa', owner, assessment, id
    else:
        raise ValueError('Value being passed is an object')
    if id is not None:
        print 'testi', id
        return self.session.query(Assessment_Result).\
        filter(Assessment_Result.id == id).one()
    elif owner is not None:
        print 'testo', owner
        return self.session.query(Assessment_Result).\
        filter(Assessment_Result.owner == owner).one()
    elif assessment is not None:
        print 'testa', assessment
        return self.session.query(Assessment_Result).\
        filter(Assessment_Result.assessment == assessment).one()
```

**convenience.py** *(child class)*

```
def retrieve_assessment_result(self, username, name):
    owner = self.retrieve_user(username)
    assessment = self.retrieve_assessment(name)
    return super(ConvenienceAPI, self).retrieve_assessment_result(owner, assessment)
```

**Traceback for question 2:** 
*(when I removed the child class to check `ID` alone)*

```
...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5.7-py2.7.egg/pyramid/config/views.py", line 501, in _requestonly_view
    response = view(request)
  File "/Users/ack/code/venv/NotssWEB/notssweb/views/views.py", line 368, in get_assessment_result
    assessment_result = api.retrieve_assessment_result(assessment_result_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notssdb/api/object.py", line 313, in retrieve_assessment_result
    id, = args[0] # <-- this the issue? see object.py above
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `id,` means a tuple, and it tries to unpack the `int`

Comment: This should simply be `id = args[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using *tuple assignment*; you are trying to assign one integer to a *tuple* of targets. Even with just one target, that requires your right-hand expression to produce a sequence with an equal amount of elements.

Either remove the comma, remove the `[0]` slicing, or add a comma to the right-hand-side to make it a tuple as well:

```
id = args[0]
```

or

```
id, = args
```

or

```
id, = args[0],
```

but the latter option is a rather inefficient version of the first.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Martjin! Makes understanding so much easier :) Any thoughts on how to approach the first question?

Comment: @thesayhey: I can't see I follow what your first question is trying to ask.

Comment: I have updated the question above. Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: @thesayhey: it sounds like you have a question pretty specific to a framework I have no experience with.

Comment: No problem. Thank you for helping me solve the first question with great explanation/example.